# How python declarative attribute pattern is called

Tags: python, oop, django-models, dsl, class-members

What is a name of the pattern that allows to define object instance variables as class variables?

Usually python object attributes are defined in `__init__` method. Few libraries allow to define object attributes outside `__init__`:

```py
# django models
class User(Model):
    name = fields.StringField()
    lastname = fields.StringField()

# django forms
class LoginForm(Form)
    username = fields.StringField()
    password = fields.PasswordField()

# elasticsearch_dsl
class Post(DocType):
    title = Text()
    created_at = Date()
    published = Boolean()
```

What is the name of this pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django, Elasticsearch DSL, and many other packages allow class level variables to declare/impose type-of-instance variables, reinforce behavior, transformation. **I do not think there is a single official name for this pattern**, yet usually it is called:

- Declarative Style Class API
- Declarative Class Definitions
- Declarative API Classes
- Declarative Class Attributes
- Modern Class DSL

Mind the term 'design pattern' was defined in the context of the "true" OOP languages such as Java and Smalltalk, as a way to handle some shortcomming, and not necesery applicable to solutions specific to Python. Functional programmers, for instance deny that work desing pattern is applicable to functional programming (since it is comletely free of any shortcomings:)
Thus, likely, here is no official name for declarative attributes. Perhaps, "idiomatic" Python Class DSL might be better term than "pattern".

While such API offer other controls such as different parent classes, hooks, etc the most striking feature is use of class variables to model the similarly named instance variables.

The modern Class DSL API are usually used in [model transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_transformation), Active-Record or Data-Mapper patterns, yet is not limited too.

Django is classic example of Active-Record implementation, which is defined by [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) as f

> The active record pattern is an approach to accessing data in a
> database. A database table or view is wrapped into a class. Thus, an
> object instance is tied to a single row in the table... The wrapper class
> implements accessor methods or properties for each column in the table or
> view.

"

Technique, on which such 'magic' declarative class oriented API packages are based called  meta-programming. Even Python does not have any means to declare object or class variables out of box, it offers means to create such declaration, via meta programming, specific DSL API, which is exploited by Django, SQL Alchemy, Elastic Search and alike, typically using class variables. While class-variable DSL most often used in object serialization to other models/formats, generic class declaration packages that aim at improving and "de[dunder](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dunder)ifying" Python OOP in general are not unheard of, e.g. https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs

Few side notes:

- The modern class API DSLs resembles both
  a) instance variable/attribute declaration static language
  b) prototype-based programming (at least if you
  recall that class is an object itself). Which make it easy to grasp
  for devs with some static or js background.
- Personally I am ok with normal classic DSLs, though common believe is that
  a DSL is too much overhead for an average programmer to learn, provided
  the documentation is typically scarce, and any changes to DSL design might
  need above-average skills, so OO modeling works best in enterprise software
  development.

Comment: It's not quite what I'm asking. Usually attributes are declared in `__init__`, does this approach has its name?

Comment: attributes are setup in __init__, not really defined... May be ORM Class Model Definition ... Class(y) DSL ... Declarative Class level modeling? Some manuals refer to it as "the declarative style seen in other popular ORMs like SQLAlchemy or Django." http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html

Comment: with addtions of forms probably ORM to be removed. Yet still all examples are some model-transformation declarative API. I bet that pattern (constructor/initializer inheretance from superclass + declaration attribute) is seldom needed outside of APIs and model transformation. So now just Declarative API Classes/Declarative Class Attributes. This phrase migth also cover also case when one class is used to declare other class attributes or objects attributes. You might wish to browse several dynamic ORMS they are full of fancy terminology which might fit your needs.

Comment: sorry for repeating itself. init is for initialization only, NOT declaration. If you wish your have two patterns/techniques - field declaration/data modelling with class attributes, and initialization with an inherited initialization method.

Comment: Approach, used in developing such 'magic' declarative class oriented API is called in python metaprogramming https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/12/01/a-primer-on-python-metaclasses

Comment: _dedunderification_ (cool packages/dudes releaving application coders from drudgery of learning and using any double-underscored methods). Dunder itself brief, cool and compact synonym to double underscore.

Comment: Would you agree with that there is no single name for this pattern, yet sometimes it is called: "Declarative Style Classes", "Declarative Class Definitions", "Declarative API Classes" or "Declarative Class Attributes"?